# 2 ContentViews side by side with swipe action between them

Tags: java, android, view, pagination

I am finding it hard to put into words what I would like to do. I want to have 2 'pages' to my app a bit similar to the homepage on an android device, where I can swipe one way and show a different ContentView. The best I can do is show some really horrible looking images I did really quickly to hopefully demonstrate:

[image] [image] [image]

With each page having it's own buttons and UIWidgets. A bit like the photo gallery I guess. I would just like a little nudge in the right direction on how to implement this. I did something very similar for iPhone using a ScrollView and setting the pages within that, can I do something similar for android?